# How to write a hive query in command line having a variable within quotes

Tags: hive

I have the following script which should give me all the tables having the mentioned strings in their name. :

```
names_list=(aa ab ac ad)
for i in ${names_list[@]}
do  
hive -e "show tables like '"''*$i*''"'">all_tables_list
done
```

I am not getting the correct result.
Can you please let me know the issue with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `hiveconf` option of hive to pass variables to hive command. Write your shell like this:-

```
names_list=(aa ab ac ad)
for i in ${names_list[@]}
do  
hive -hiveconf tables=$i -e "use dbname;show tables like '${hiveconf:tables}'" > all_tables_list
done
```